# Comparing images in an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to compare the images in an array I have for my card matching game as I'm trying to get the logic behind matching my cards. I don't know how however. Would anyone be willing to explain to me what I've got to do in order to achieve this?

I've got a variable that holds my array of 20 images as cards.

```
let cardsArray = [
  { name: "tony", img: "Tony-Soprano.jpg" },
  { name: "tony", img: "Tony-Soprano.jpg" },
  { name: "adriana-la-cerva", img: "Adriana-La-Cerva.jpg" },
  { name: "adriana-la-cerva", img: "Adriana-La-Cerva.jpg" },
...
```

I've got a function that loops through the array in order to shuffle them.

```
  const container = document.querySelector(".Soprano-game");

  for (let i of array) {
    const code = `
    <div class="Soprano-card">
      <div class="Back-card">
        <img class="Soprano_image" src="assets/img/Characters/${i.img}" alt="Characters">
      </div>
      <div class="front-card">
        <img class="Soprano_image" src="assets/img/Sopranos-Title.jpg" alt="Sopranos-Title">
      </div>
    </div>
    `;

    container.innerHTML += code;
  }
}
```

Would mean a lot if someone could help explain to me what I've got to do in order to understand the logic behind matching my cards. I want to understand how? The how is the confusing bit. I believe I need to get the value (the src) in order to compare, then push it to a new array. I understand that part actually writing the syntax is what's confusing me here.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: There is no [shuffling](https://www.google.com/search?q=shuffle+array+es6+site:stackoverflow.com) in that code

Comment: what part is confusing? it's best to walk through the steps, consider how each one will be handled, then ask specific questions about specific things.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a complete a beginner and know nothing. 
I'm creating a card matching game - I've done everything, the shuffling, the styling etc. The only thing remaining is the matching logic. I've read that in order to do so, I need to create a function that compares the imgs when clicked. Its the syntax that's the confusing part. Haven't got a clue where to start.